# Volume Flow Problem with Nitrogen

Tags: homework-and-exercises, fluid-dynamics

If I have a tank of nitrogen gas at 2000psi and a pipe of 10mm cross sectional area and 1 meter long how long would it take to fill another, initially empty tank, to 5L at 1000psi? Assume to 2000psi never drops and the initial source is unlimited

I have tried a couple of things so far:

1. Renouard Equation: $p_i^2-p_f^2=46,742\rho Lq^{1.82}D^{-4.82}\implies 4391.11$ L/s unreasonable
2. Panhandle Equation: -12166 L/s unreasonable
3. Weymouth Equation: 1066 L/s better but still an awful lot
4. Tried using experimental data: with this I know at the initial condition of 2000psi I have 228ft$^3$ and in 5 seconds the pressure drops to 1750psi but I no longer know how much gas is left.

Any help is much appreciated on this, thanks.

Comment: You will have choked flow in the pipe, and the fluid velocity will be sonic velocity.  Use the density of the high pressure nitrogen with sonic velocity to calculate the time required.